# How to set default values on DTO nestJs?

Tags: node.js, typescript, validation, nestjs, default

```
import { IsString, IsNumber, IsOptional, IsUUID, Min, Max } from 'class-validator';
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';

export class QueryCollateralTypeDto {
  @Transform(({ value }) => parseInt(value))
  @IsNumber()
  @IsOptional()
  page: number;

  @Transform(({ value }) => parseInt(value))
  @IsNumber()
  @IsOptional()
  limit: number;

  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  select: string;
}
```

I want to set default integer values for page and limit and string value for select, (example page value of integer 1, limit value of integer 10, and select value of "field1,field2,...")

Comment: btw there's nothing on nestjs here, it's just `class-validator`. Read their docs: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body. You're allowed to, even encouraged, to [write your own answer to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), simply add that as an answer in its own right.

Answer (score 34):

Okey i found a solution i guess you just initalize the variables at DTO

```
import { IsString, IsNumber, IsOptional, IsUUID, Min, Max } from 'class-validator';
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';

export class QueryCollateralTypeDto {
  @Transform(({ value }) => parseInt(value))
  @IsNumber()
  @IsOptional()
  page: number = 1;

  @Transform(({ value }) => parseInt(value))
  @IsNumber()
  @IsOptional()
  limit: number = 10;

  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  select: string = 'name,description';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set default values in the service and the function that uses the data like the example below if it is the case for you. If you don't pass any value to the function the default values will be set.

```
exampleFunction(data: QueryCollateralTypeDto) {
    const { page = 1, limit = 10, select = 'field1' } = data;
    ...
}
```

Comment: i found another way directly on the DTO file   page: number = 1;   limit: number = 10;   select: string = 'name';

Answer (score 2):

You have to annotate your controller or method with ValidationPipe  with the option transform on true (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation)

```js
//at the controller level:
@Controller('some_controller')
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true}))

export class SomeController {
  constructor() {}

  //or at the method level
  @Post()
  @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true}))
  create(
    @Body() someDto: SomeDto,
  ): Promise<someEntity> {
    return this.service.create(someDto);
  }
```

Comment: This exactly uses class-validator, class-transformer in Controller. Remember set in `main.ts`: app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());